# Perl: Run recursive jobs in parallel

Tags: perl, recursion, parallel-processing

I have a recursive function that calls a system command to list files and directory. For each directory it will call itself again.

This process could take a while. This is why I would like to run parallel jobs.

I was looking into ForkManager but it would not allow creating new sub forks. As the amount of subprocess should be limited to 10 I was thinking of a 'worker' concept. Having 10 workers waiting for jobs to be executed.

My recursive function:

```
sub pullDataFromDbWithDirectory {
    my $_dir = $_[0];
    my @list = ();

    if ($itemCount lt $maxNumberOfItems) {
        my @retval = grep { /dir|file/ } map { s/^Dir\s+|^File\s+|\n//g; $_ } qx($omnidb -filesystem $filesystem  '$label'  -listdir '$_dir');

        foreach my $item (@retval) {
            $itemCount++;

            push(@list,$item) if $item =~ /^file/;

            if ($item =~ /^dir/) {
                my $subdir = "$_dir/$item";
                $data{$subdir} = ();

                if ($recursive) {
                    pullDataFromDbWithDirectory($subdir);
                }
            }
        }

        $data{$_dir} = \@list;
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Update:

The problem is solved. Thanks for the input. I modified my code:

```
sub pullDataFromDbWithDirectory {
    my $_dir = $_[0];

    if ($itemCount <= $maxNumberOfItems) {
        my @retval = grep { /dir|file/ } map { s/^Dir\s+|^File\s+|\n//g; $_ } qx($omnidb -filesystem $filesystem  '$label'  -listdir '$_dir');

        foreach my $item (@retval) {
            $itemCount++;
            my $file = "$_dir/$item";
            push(@data,$file);

            if ($item =~ /^dir/) {
                $worker->enqueue($file);
                print "Add $file to queue\n" if $debug;
            }
        }
    }
}

sub doOperation () {
    my $ithread = threads->tid();
    while (my $folder = $worker->dequeue()) {
        print "Read $folder from queue\n" if $debug;
        pullDataFromDbWithDirectory($folder);
    }
}

my @threads = map threads->create(\&doOperation), 1 .. $maxNumberOfParallelJobs;
pullDataFromDbWithDirectory($directory);
$worker->enqueue((undef) x $maxNumberOfParallelJobs);
$_->join for @threads;
```

Comment: You need interprocess communication for that. One module that supports IPC is Child: https://metacpan.org/pod/Child

Comment: Would it be acceptable to discover target directories recursively, then process them in parallel? If you don't specifically need child forks, might as well go with the simplest thing that works.

Comment: The problem is that I have to run the omnidb command to list files and folders. And it does not support recursive listing. Foreach subfolder I have to run the omnidb command which takes quite some time. I would like to run them in parallel. Maybe fill the directories into a queue which is being processed in parallel..

Comment: Have a look at [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rewrite your code to use an appropriate Perl module, like [File::Find](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) it is much more effective.

```
use File::Find;
my %data;
find(\&wanted, @directories_to_search);
sub wanted {
  $data{$File::Find::dir} = $_;

}
```

For paralel operation I would use Thread::Queue like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;

use threads;
use Thread::Queue;

my $q = Thread::Queue->new();    # A new empty queue
my %seen: shared;

# Worker thread
my @thrs = threads->create(\&doOperation ) for 1..5;#for 5 threads
add_file_to_q('/tmp/');
$q->enqueue('//_DONE_//') for @thrs;
$_->join() for @thrs;

sub add_file_to_q {
  my $dir = shift;
  my @files = `ls -1 $dir/`;chomp(@files);
  #add files to queue
  foreach my $f (@files){
    # Send work to the thread
    $q->enqueue($f);
    print "Pending items: "$q->pending()."\n";
  }
}



sub doOperation () {
    my $ithread = threads->tid() ;
    while (my $filename = $q->dequeue()) {
      # Do work on $item
      sleep(1) if ! defined $filename;
      return 1 if $filename eq '//_DONE_//';
      next if $seen{$filename};
      print "[id=$ithread]\t$filename\n";
      $seen{$filename} = 1;
      ### add files if it is a directory (check with symlinks, no file with //_DONE_// name!)
      add_file_to_q($filename) if -d $filename;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure File::Find is much more effective because I am not parsing any filesystem. I am running some omnidb command for HP Data Protector that gives back a list of files and directories. But it does not support recursive listing, which I try to implement. For each subdirectory I have to re run the omnidb command with the specified dir. Thanks for the Thread:Queue example. I will have a look into it

Comment: thanks for your solution. It works now. I added my working code above.